# git log with 10 caracters in hash

Tags: git, github

I need get ten caracters of hash commit with command git log

Command:

`git log --name-status --author=<myname> --after=2023-02-01 --pretty-format:"commit: #%H" > delivery.txt`

Result:

```
commit: #7eba42113e41720932c407d864cb3d90a8e95de7
M package.json
```

I need:

```
commit: #7eba42113e
M package.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`--abbrev-commit`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---abbrev-commit)  in combination with [`--abbrev=<n>`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---abbrevltngt):

```
git log --name-status --author=<myname> --after=2023-02-01 --abbrev=10 --abbrev-commit
```